# Join two tables where one table has a specific value

Tags: mysql

I have this code below that returns the names that aren't in the first table. My issue is I need to use where on the first table before I do the join.

```
SELECT *
FROM Mock A
    LEFT JOIN List B ON (A.Person = B.Name)
WHERE A.Person IS NULL OR B.Name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT *
FROM KyleMock A
    RIGHT JOIN List B ON (A.Person = B.Name)
WHERE A.Person IS NULL OR B.Name IS NULL
```

What I need to do on the first table is

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE Style = 'Turtle'
```

I tried

```
WHERE (A.Person IS NULL OR B.Name IS NULL) AND Style = 'Turtle'
```

This just limits my results to where Style = 'Turtle' and doesn't include the other rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out records in join condition itself, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM Mock A
    LEFT JOIN List B ON (A.Person = B.Name AND A.Style = 'Turtle')
WHERE A.Person IS NULL OR B.Name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT *
FROM KyleMock A
    RIGHT JOIN DraftList B ON (A.Person = B.Name)
WHERE A.Person IS NULL OR B.Name IS NULL
```

Comment: Perfect, do I need to do the = on both Left and Right joins or will it be enough in just one?

Comment: It depends on requirement. Both the queries in question use different tables (Mock and KyleMock) so, I don't know whether KyleMock table also has style column.